# Order entries by custom date field, with empty date-entries last in list

Tags: custom-fields, entry

I'm listing courses by a custom date field, but some courses are "on demand" and doesn't have a specific time. When using orderby="custom_field" and sort="asc" all the courses without a date shows up first in the list. How can I get them to show up at the end instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have to run two Channel Entries loops to do this, since the empty fields are essentially treated as `0`, so they will always come first in an ascending order.

First, to get your entries which *have* a custom date:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel=:courses" orderby="course_date" sort="asc" search:course_date="not IS_EMPTY"}
```

Then grab those which do *not* have a custom date:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="courses" orderby="title" sort="asc" search:course_date="IS_EMPTY"}
```

Comment: (As always Derek has a nice solution, which i like to extend :-) . Since the OP (original poster) mentions "some courses are on demand", So, why not have a checkbox/select to indicate if a course is "on demand" (e.g. has a datetime filled in), then with one channel entries loop `orderby="on_demand|course_date" sort="desc|asc"` (edit: the on_demand variable needs to be 1 for regular courses so they show up first)

Comment: GDmac: I thought of doing that, but I'm trying to make as few custom fields as I can...